# Showing that Show that $k$'th slice of space is homeomorphic to $X_j$.

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the product space $X=\prod_{i \in I} X_i$. Fix $k \in X$ and $j \in I$. Let $K= \{x \in X : x_i=k_i, \text{ when $j \ne i$} \}$ be the $k$'th slice of $X_j$. Show that $K$ is homeomorphic to $X_j$.

How does this look if we consider $X=\Bbb R^2$? I'm trying to build intuition from here. If I fix say $k=(2,2)$ and $j=2$, then is $K$ equal to the vertical line passing thourgh $(2,2)$?

What's the map I should consider here? I think I would need to send the points from the $y-$axis as $y \mapsto (2,y)$?

Comment: Yes and yes. (You haven't defined $X$ in the problem, but I assume it is that product space.) Basically, $\mathbb{R}^2$ consists of many vertical slices, the slices are lines in this case. You can think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an infinite collection of lines which are the slices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with both of your guesses. It's quite plausible that a vertical line $\{(2,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, right? Finish your proof by recalling what it means to be a homeomorphism and generalize.

Some further comments:

In general, $\mathbb{R}^2$ consists of many vertical slices and the slices here are lines. Indeed, you can think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an infinite collection/bundle of lines/slices, in other words as an infinite collection of $\mathbb{R}$'s. A topologist or a geometer would say that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a trivial fiber bundle with fiber $\mathbb{R}$. We are even in the special case where $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a trivial line bundle.

In your general exercise, $X$ is a trivial fiber bundle with fiber $X_j$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that often there is an easier particular case to build intuition as with $\Bbb R^2$ in this case.

Comment: @Lakritsa Yes, that‘s a common problem-solving strategy: Try to understand (easier) concrete examples. :-)